# Find the PDF of Z = max(X1,...,Xn) where each X is an independent random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Let $X_1$,...,$X_n$ be $n$ independent random variables each with the identical pdf $f(x)$. Let $Z = max(X_1,...,X_n).$  Find the pdf of $Z$.

---

My approach:

**Step 1:** Find the CDF

$$F_Z(z) =  n\int\limits_{z}^{z + dz}f(X_{max})dX_{max}*\int\limits_{-\infty}^{z}(f(x))^{n-1} dx$$

My reasoning here is to find the probability of one variable being at the max value and multiply that with the probability of all the other variables being at that value or less. Then I multiply all of that by $n$ because there are n ways this situation can occur.

**Step2:** Find the PDF

$$f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F_Z(z)$$

I'm stuck on step 2. Which integral do I take the derivative of? Or is it unclear because I messed up step 1 somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $P(X_{(n)} \leq x) = [P(X_i \leq x)]^n$

Since they $X_i$ are all independent and identically distributed,

$P(X_{(n)} \leq x) = P(X_1\leq x $ and $ X_2 \leq x $ and $... $ and $ X_n \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x)^n = \big(F_{X_1}(x)\big)^n$

Then the derivative of that is $$f_{X_{(n)}}(x) = n[F_{X_i}(x)]^{n-1}\cdot f_{X_i}(x)$$ by the chain rule.

Comment: I'm not following, sorry. Shouldn't it be $P(X_i \leq x)^{n-1}*P(X_i = x)$?

Comment: It's the chain rule. If say $F(x) = x^2+4$, then $d/dx (F(x))^n = n (F(x))^{n-1}\cdot F'(x) = n(x^2+4)^{n-1} 2x$.

Comment: Use the chain rule...$(g\circ h)' = (g'\circ h)\cdot h'$ where $g\circ h(x)=h(x)^n$ so $g'\circ h(x)=n (h(x))^{n-1}$

Comment: Hi Robert, I think I'm not getting it conceptually. If we have 3 variables, x, y, z, that can take on any value from 1-10. Then lets say the max value one takes is z = 6. Then it would be: $P( x \leq 6 )P(y \leq 6) P(z = 6)$ and not $P(z \leq 6)$

Comment: Are you thinking of discrete variables or continuous?  Because for continuous, $P(z=6) = 0$, because you need an interval for a probability density to add up (integrate) to a probability.